# Python: how to group similar lists inside lists with tolerance and take average?

Tags: python, list, group-by, grouping, average

**input-->  a = [[297, 151, 320], [293, 151, 305], [296, 151, 320], [295, 162, 306], [297, 160, 309], [300, 158, 321]**

> I have a list inside a list. I need to group by the third element in the list a[i][2] with tolerance + or - 5

**output_1--> a = [[[297, 151, 320], [293, 151, 318], [296, 151, 321]], [[295, 162, 306], [297, 160, 309], [300, 158, 305]]**

> Later I need to take an average of each subgroup such as  [297, 151, 320], [293, 151, 318], [296, 151, 321] = [(297+293+296)/3,(151+151+151)/3,(320+318+321)/3] simillarly for the next group
>
> final output

**final_output--> a=[[[295,151,320]],[[297,160,307]]]**

**Can anyone help with this ?**

Comment: I think those averages are wrong. e.g. you have `(151+151+151)/3`, but the only three lists with `151` are `[297, 151, 320], [293, 151, 305], [296, 151, 320]`, where the second element doesn't belong in this grouping because its `305` vs `320`, which is a tolerance of `15`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, i dont get what u want. Cuz ur value for each list are not consistent. But, did u mean like this one?

```
a = [[297, 151, 320], [293, 151, 305], [296, 151, 320], [295, 162, 306], [297, 160, 309], [300, 158, 321]]
b = []
i = -1
for x in range(len(a)):
    if (x%3) == 0:
        b.append([])
        i += 1
    ave = int(sum(a[x])/len(a[x]))
    b[i].append(ave)
print(b)
```

output:
`[[256, 249, 255], [254, 255, 259]]`

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to create a generator function to do the tolerance grouping. This function assumes the list is sorted, so you need to pass a sorted list in, or modify it to do the sorting in the function. I'm sure someone will find a way to do this with `itertools.groupby`.

```
def groupby_tolerance(lst, tolerance):
    result = [lst[0]]

    for prev, curr in zip(lst, lst[1:]):
        if curr[2] - prev[2] > tolerance:
            yield result
            result = []
        result.append(curr)

    yield result
```

Then called this function on  your sorted list(by the 3rd item):

```
from operator import itemgetter

a = [[297, 151, 320], [293, 151, 305], [296, 151, 320], [295, 162, 306], [297, 160, 309], [300, 158, 321]]

grouped = groupby_tolerance(sorted(a, key=itemgetter(2)), 5)
```

Which gives the grouping:

```
[[[293, 151, 305], [295, 162, 306], [297, 160, 309]], [[297, 151, 320], [296, 151, 320], [300, 158, 321]]]
```

Then you can zip the corresponding elements and calculate the average:

```
from statistics import mean

averages = [[mean(x) for x in zip(*group)] for group in grouped]

print(averages)
```

**Averages:**

```
[[295, 157.66666666666666, 306.6666666666667], [297.6666666666667, 153.33333333333334, 320.3333333333333]]
```

Comment: @Ashwath No worries. If it helped you please mark it as correct for future readers :)